# Determine the generator of an ideal of ring of integers

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

I am trying to find the generators of the ideal $(3)$ in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-83}]$ the ring of integers is $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-83}}{2}\right]$ I evaluated the Minkowski constant and it is $2/\pi \sqrt{83} \sim 5.8;$ then I checked the minimal polynomial of $x^2-x+84/2, $ which is reducible module $3,$ hence the ideal $(3)$ is generated by two elements, right? Did I miss something? I want to say the ring of integers is not a UFD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have touched upon several different ideas here.

**Generators of the ideal $(3)$**. Usually, when you talk about the generators of $(3)$, you mean its generators as an abelian group.

Define $\theta := \tfrac 1 2 (1 + \sqrt{-83})$. We know that the ring of integers $\mathbb Z[\theta]$ is generated by $\{1, \theta \}$ as an abelian group, so $(3)$ is generated by $\{3, 3\theta \}$ as an abelian group.

But having read the remainder of your question, it looks like this is not what you're after! What you're really interested in are the generators of the *ideal class group* for $\mathbb Z[\theta]$. (In fact, to prove that $\mathbb Z [\theta]$ is not a UFD, we don't even need to explicitly identify a set of generators for the ideal class group - it's enough to show that the ideal class group is non-trivial.)

**Minkowski constant.** The fact that $\frac 4 \pi \times \frac {2!} {2^2} \sqrt{83} \approx. 5.8$ implies that the ideal class group is generated by prime ideals that are factors of $(2)$, $(3)$ or $(5)$.

**Dedekind's criterion.** Dedekind's criterion is a way of factorising $(3)$ as a product of primes.

As you pointed out, we have the factorisation
$$ x^2 - x + \frac {84}{2} \equiv x(x-1) \mod 3,$$

so Dedekind's criterion says that
$$ (3) = (3, \theta)(3, \theta - 1)$$
is the prime factorisation of $(3)$ in $\mathbb Z[\theta]$.

**Whether $\mathbb Z[\theta]$ is a UFD.** This is equivalent to asking whether the ideal class group is trivial, i.e. whether all ideals are principal.

Why don't we check whether $(3, \theta)$ is principal? The answer must be "no". Note that $(3, \theta)$ has norm $3$. If it was principal, then there would exist $x, y \in \mathbb Z$ such that $(3, \theta) = (x + y\theta)$. But then
$$ 3 = N(3, \theta) = N(x + y\theta) =  (x + \tfrac 1 2 y)^2 + 83(\tfrac 1 2 y)^2,$$
which is impossible.

So $\mathbb Z[\theta]$ is *not* a principal ideal domain, and hence, is not a unique factorisation domain.

Comment: Thanks that helpful, that what I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

The minimal polynomial of $\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt{-83}}{2}$ is $f = x^2 - x + 84/4 = x^2 - x + 21$. Modulo $3$ this factors as $$f \equiv x^2 - x = x(x-1) \pmod 3,$$
so by the Kummer-Dedekind theorem the ideal $(3)$ factors into primes in $\mathbb{Z}\bigg[\frac{1+\sqrt{-83}}{2}\bigg]$ as $(3) = (3, \alpha)(3, \alpha-1)$.

The ideal $(3)$ is principal, generated by $3$. You can show that the prime factors are not principal, e.g. using the field norm:

If $(3,\alpha) = (\beta)$ then $N(\beta)$ divides both $N(3) = 3^2$ and $N(\alpha) = f(0) = 21 = 3\cdot 7$, so $N(\beta) = 3$.

If we write $\beta = a+b\alpha$ then $$N(\beta)=(a+b\alpha)(a+b(1-\alpha)) = \ldots = a^2+ab + 21b^2.$$

The equation $a^2+ab + 21b^2 = 3$ is an ellipse in the $(a,b)$-plane without integral points, so there is no such $\beta$.

Comment: How could you determine that the ellipse has no integral points?

Comment: I plotted it (with a grid in the background). It's a very small ellipse, so there are very few candidates for integral points, and you can see that it misses them all.